# Google App Engine Federated Login 500 Server Error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-openid

First of all, thanks you for your time and help.

I have an app engine application that use federated login.  However it is giving me 500 Server Error for the past 2 hours.

Is it a known issue with this service at this momement?

Thanks again.

Bill

Answer (score 2):

As per [AppEngine's authentication documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/auth):

> (**Experimental**) Open to all users with an OpenID Provider:
>   If your application uses authentication, **anyone who has an account with an OpenID Provider** may sign in.

Google has [announced deprecation of OpenID2](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/02/welcome-openid-connect.html) a while ago and [sunset the corresponding APIs last week](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/04/a-final-farewell-to-clientlogin-oauth.html), thus unfortunately these Google authentication APIs are not available through AppEngine any longer.

Comment: Miguel, thank you so much for your comments.  I now remember long time back I did receive email communication from Google regarding the same.  It just totally skipped my attention.  I now have to migrate to the new scheme.   Thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome, happy to help and good luck with the migration!