# Should I still be using App Engine's Users Python API?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-signin

Given Google's latest move towards OpenID Connect and the lack of extensive documentation on GAE's Users API, wanted to ask the community if it's a good idea to continue to use Users API

Should we expect this to become deprecated in the near future and look to move away from this service as soon as possible?

Much appreciated!!

Also, just for clarity sake I'm referring to: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/

Comment: Although I am interested in the answer, I have to mark this question as "off topic" for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Google deprecates some service it doesn't do that overnight, ample time (many months, typically over a year) comes between the official announcement and when the service discontinuation becomes effective, with detailed plans, guidelines and procedures for migrations to whichever alternative solutions are available and recommended at that time.

Jumping ahead to a solution without a valid reason may actually be worse. For example the Users Api has been around long before OpenID 2.0, which is now deprecated :)

The functionality of the Users API is still very much valid for many apps (and even various other pieces of Google infrastructure) which do not actually need the additional features of OpenID Connect. The API and the service is simple, mature and stable. In other words I don't think there is a valid reason for Google to deprecate the API, at least not at this time.

So I wouldn't worry about it yet, at least not for apps already implemented - if it ain't broken don't fix it :)

For new apps, especially if it's unclear if they would need at some point some functionality not presently provided by the Users API, it *might* make more sense to go directly for another authentication method.

Comment: Thanks! Been digging around a bit more and it seems like it's being deprecated to an extent, at least for the federated accounts portion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860145/google-app-engine-federated-login-500-server-error

Comment: The API referenced as being deprecated in that Q is the OpenID 2.0 one (which I used as an example), not the Users one.

Comment: Oh that's true -- authentication using the base Google Accounts API still is functioning... I guess I've been working with the experimental federated login option connected with Users API so was incorrectly linking those two services

Comment: Check this guide for chosing the right auth solution for your context: https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth

Comment: Thanks! -- really helpful